# Regex to extract the text having this patern

Tags: java, regex

I have lines of text having this form

- Introduction
- Installation
- 1.2 Windows Installation
- 1.3 Linux Installation
- 1.3.1 ............
- 1.3.1.1 ..........

I want a REGEX to detect and extract the digit having this form :
X. or X.X or X.X.X or XX.X or X.XX ...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What regex do you have right now? And what have you tried?

Comment: matches = string.scan(/\d+/)

Comment: And do you get an error from this? Please include this as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case here is the right REGEX : [0-9.]+(\s*\w)+

implementation in java :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9.]+(\\s*\\w)+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
boolean found = m.matches();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[^.][0-9.]+` as the regex.

1. `[^.]` will drop any `.` in the beginning
2. `[0-9.]+` will match combination of digits and dots.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] testStrs = { "Introduction", "1.2 Windows Installation", "1.3 Linux Installation",
                "1.3.1 ............", "1.3.1.1 .........." };
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^.][0-9.]+");
        for (String str : testStrs) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1.2
1.3
1.3.1
1.3.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following expression will match all of your examples:

```
/(^[\d\.]+)/gm
```

The `gm` flags are required if you want to run the expression against multiple lines and get all the matches.

It should be noted that the expression will match any periods preceding or immediately following a number, so the examples below will also be matched:

```
.1.2 The numbers here will be matched
1.2. These numbers will also be matched
```

If this is a problem, I recommend removing these periods using `replaceFirst()`, `substring()`, or something similar.